# Multi Auth Laravel 5.4 using two middleware only

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I want to create two middleware to redirect the authenticated user, if it is an admin it will be redirected to the backoffice otherwise it will be redirected to a simple dashboard for simple users.

But I want to use only the users table without adding another table for the admins.

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
<?php

 class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
        {
            return redirect('/admin/home');
        }
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

DashboardController.php

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('authFront.layoutAuthenticatedUser.dashboard');
}


}
```

web.php

```
    Route::get('/us-admin', function () { return redirect('/admin/home');    })->name('admin.dashboard');

   // Authentication Routes...
   $this->get('login',    'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('auth.login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('auth.login');
   $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('auth.register');

   $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('auth.logout');


   // Change Password Routes...
   $this->get('change_password',   'Auth\ChangePasswordController@showChangePasswordForm')->name('auth.change_password');
   $this->patch('change_password', 'Auth\ChangePasswordController@changePassword')->name('auth.change_password');

   // Password Reset Routes...
   $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('auth.password.reset');
   $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('auth.password.reset');
  $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
  $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('auth.password.reset');

   Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

});
   Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

Comment: Calling your users simple isn't going to win you any friends :) Seriously though what have you got so far other than a nice idea? Where are you stuck? What issues are you facing?

Comment: thank you @Dale, I have a back office already exists for admins, now I want that if a user wants to authenticate via the front of my website, it will be redirected to a small backoffice with a profile and other elements I do not want That the user accesses the back office of admins.

Comment: just make column to store user role (admin, super admin, user)

Comment: @HoàngĐăng Already done, the problem is that the test on the middleware does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish user roles in this case, or have an optional boolean field on the users table for is_admin. Then in middleware it would simply be something like:

```
class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (!Auth::user()->admin()) {
            return redirect()->to('user-dashboard');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

So in your case I would create a separate middleware for each role post-authorization. Then you would apply AdminMiddleware to all routes prefixed with 'admin', SimpleUserMiddleware to all other routes, for example.

Comment: I have already set roles management, with a foreign key in the users table with the "role_id" field, but I have already tried to create a middlware which for the simple users but it does not work

Comment: but how ?! can you help please

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check roles in `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware which do already exist by default and restrict the routes by creating an admin middleware

In `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
            {
                return redirect('/admin/home');    
            }
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In `app/Http/Middleware/AuthenticateAdmin.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class AuthenticateAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check() || Auth::user()->role_id != 1)
        {
            if ($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In `app/Http/Kernal.php` add this line in `$routeMiddleware` array

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateAdmin::class,
```

In `routes/web.php`

```
Route::middleware('admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
});
```

In `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` add this function

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->role_id == 1) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.home'));
    }
    return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Careful with this one, it will redirect you back to the roles homepage from inner pages if you apply it to all the routes in the group.

Comment: this is not a middleware which you use to apply for every routes, it is default middleware which checks when you are authenticated. To apply for all routes you have to create another simple admin middleware

Comment: it redirect me to  not found page

Comment: /home and /admin/home are just placeholders in this example, you'd have to setup routes for them.

Comment: i know , i setup my own routes but it doesn't work, I think it does not check the role_id

Comment: please update your question with your code, so that we can correct if needed

Comment: does this helped you ?

Comment: @Adeebbasheer it's not working , it's redirect admin and smiple to the same path "/dashboard" and show 404 error Page not found

Comment: @YassineMabrouk If I can get some access i can make it work for you

Comment: i just need to know the structure, whether you are calling right view etc

Comment: @Adeebbasheer give me your email